# Handling unfound data in mySQL procedure loop

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures

I think I'm narrowing in on my issue. I have a loop that is only firing once:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `thread_updates` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `thread_updates`()
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE my_curr_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
-- DECLARE other vars
DECLARE fixer_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT DISTINCT(id)
  FROM log
  WHERE date >= '2018-01-01';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

OPEN fixer_cursor;
REPEAT
  FETCH fixer_cursor INTO my_curr_id;
  IF NOT done THEN
    SELECT data FROM table WHERE id = my_curr_id; -- This may not exist 
    -- Do other stuff with 'data' or NULL from above
  END IF;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE fixer_cursor;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I think the issue may be that inside the `IF NOT done THEN` loop, I have a few select statements that may be trying to select results that don't exist (not found).

This is fine (for me) as the logic continues along using NULL values in those spots, but I suspect that my `CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND` is catching the `NOT FOUND` warning that these selects throw inside the loop and are thus stopping the entire loop prematurely.

How can I listen for `NOT FOUND` warning on my cursor only?

Or, how can I suppress the `NOT FOUND` warning in my MAYBE FOUND select statements inside my loop so my loop continues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved the issue by implementing a counter in a loop rather than relying on the `NOT FOUND` handler:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `thread_updates` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `thread_updates`()
BEGIN

DECLARE my_total INT DEFAULT NULL; -- Declare total
DECLARE my_counter INT DEFAULT 0; -- Declare counter starting at 0
DECLARE my_curr_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
-- DECLARE other vars
DECLARE fixer_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT DISTINCT(id)
  FROM log
  WHERE date >= '2018-01-01';

OPEN fixer_cursor;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO my_total; -- Get total number of rows

my_fixerloop: LOOP

  FETCH fixer_cursor INTO my_curr_id;
  IF my_counter >= my_total THEN -- Compare counter to total
    CLOSE fixer_cursor;
    LEAVE my_fixerloop;
  END IF;

  SET my_counter = my_counter + 1; -- Increment by one for each record

  SELECT data FROM table WHERE id = my_curr_id; -- This may not exist 
  -- Do other stuff with 'data' or NULL from above

END LOOP;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```